# Groupby then do the self define function in r dplyr

Tags: r

The original data is the above dataframe.
I want to (1) group by ID (2) define a function to evaluate the grade (3) output the complete dataframe(as the below dataframe).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQT3A.jpg)

How can this be done in r using dplyr?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Evaluate = c("Low", "Medium", "High")[rank(Grade)]) %>%
    ungroup
```